# Does NetBeans IDE has a "show definition" view?

Tags: netbeans, ide

Is there a mode in which NetBeans can show the definition of the symbol under cursor in a separate view (ie. not have to 'Navigate/Go to Source')? Like Source Insight. Or how VS has now 'Peek Definition', but I prefer though a separate tool window, not inline peek.

Comment: A NetBeans plugin module would also be acceptable...